# how to use 'concat' with an unspecified number of fields

Tags: mysql, excel, vba

I need to extract data from 5 tables (`dettagliliti1`, `dettagliliti2`, .... , `dettagliliti5`) and, to do that, I use a `For...next` loop to change the table name in the query string below

```
        SQLStr = "SELECT `Ufficio`, `Anno`, `RG`, `IdLiteUtente`, `dettagliliti" & Q & "`.* " & _
        " FROM (`dettagliliti" & Q & "` INNER JOIN `litiutente` ON `litiutente`.`IdLite` =" & _
        " `dettagliliti" & Q & "`.`IdLite`) INNER JOIN `liti` ON `liti`.`IdLite` = `litiutente`.`IdLite`" & _
        " WHERE `litiutente`.`utente` = '" & Utenti(0, Ut) & _
        "' AND `dettagliliti" & Q & "`.`IdEvento` NOT IN" & _
        " (Select `IdEvento` FROM `Informative` WHERE `IdUtente`='" & Utenti(0, Ut) & "' AND" & _
        " `IdTabella`='" & Q & "')" & _
        " ORDER BY `IdEvento`"
```

I chose this way because the five tables have different number of fields but, to reduce the number of the queries to execute, I thought about using `GROUP_CONCAT` to get all the fields of each of the tables `dettagliliti` in one field (so after i can split single values) but I'm not able to use the right syntax.

Every help is appreciated.

Comment: Smells like poor database design.

Comment: I't a database who gets (and updates) its data from a website structured with five table for each data search.